# TFS - Merge relationship - How to exclude ?

Tags: database, tfs, merge, branch, relationship

We have a case here where a developer creates a wrong branch. The branch should be: $\projectA\branch01\pg5Dev from $\projectA\main\pg5Dev\ but he creates a $\projectA\branch01\ from $\projectA\main\pg5Dev.

We deleted the folder and creates the branch again, but the merge relationship in merge wizard remains.

We need to know the database structure of Merge Relations ships to remove $\projectA\branch01\, because everytime we will make a merge, the worng branch is appearing in combobox of merge wizard.

Please, help us identify the tables in database that have this wrong record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the incorrect branch isn't needed then I would recommend destroying it.  Once it is destroyed, it will no longer show up in the combobox.  You can destroy it by running "tf destroy ".  Note that a destroy is non-recoverable and it will delete all of the history for that branch.

Comment: Whilst I'm not a big fan of using "destory" I think in this instance it's the appropriate option. Just make sure you have the correct server path in the command before you run it!